# Updates to table in cursor not reflecting in merge statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a plsql code

1)I am updating column bucket to 'Test' for record say R1 in table1 in cursor loop code

2)And I have merge statement on the table1 and I am not even updating record R1 in this merge

Expected result

Bucket value to be test for R1 record but it is showing bucket as 'F' previous value

However if I add select in to statement before merge to check what was previous bucket value
Bucket is updating to 'IP' as expected

Not sure why it is working when I add select statement before merge.

What is select statement doing is it giving hint to take latest data from table t1?

Why update in cursor not working without adding that select into statement which I added for debugging

Comment: Please edit your question to include a reproducible test case.  If we have to guess about exactly what your code is doing, it is unlikely that we will guess your exact implementation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.